# Is it a simple way to fill a cell of GridBagLayout with a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Is it a simple way to create a panel inside a `BorderLayout` which will fill a cell?

Here is a simple example, where I'd like the grey panel (`pnlTitle`) to be as wide as the containing cell (100 pixels), but I'd like to do it without something like `pnlTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));`

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestCode2_InsideColumn {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(400, 200);
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 150));

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    window.add(panelMain);

    JLabel labelN = new JLabel("North");
    panelMain.add(labelN, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel labelS = new JLabel("South");
    panelMain.add(labelS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    GridBagLayout innerLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints innerConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Second (and last) column won't have fixed size, so last number is useless
    innerLayout.columnWidths = new int[] {100, 100};

    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(innerLayout);
    innerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 220, 250));
    panelMain.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    innerConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    innerConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
    innerConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
    innerConstraints.gridx = 0;
    innerConstraints.gridy = 0;

    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Title");
    JPanel pnlTitle = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pnlTitle.add(lblTitle);
    innerLayout.setConstraints(pnlTitle, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(pnlTitle);

    innerConstraints.gridx = 1;
    innerConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Label");
    innerLayout.setConstraints(lblDescription, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(lblDescription);

    window.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: `innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH`?

Comment: Damn! That was pretty simple indeed. Thanx! Too bad you didn't write a proper answer, so I can't mark it as complete. But you can still do it if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH
```

From the JavaDocs

```
BOTH
public static final int BOTH
Resize the component both horizontally and vertically.
```

Comment: Do we need to add this line of code after adding each control to the GridBagLayout or enough to add once after defining the GridBagConstraints? It didn't work for me.

Comment: You can re-use the same instance of `GridBagConstraints` (I tend use one and it's based properties and then update those properties which need to be changed), when you call `add` GridBagLayout` will make a copy for itself